# Can't login to yahoo with Python mechanize

Tags: python, authentication, yahoo

Up until a few months ago I was able to log into my yahoo account using mechanize with the following code:

```
self.br = mechanize.Browser()
self.br.set_handle_robots(False)
self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT    6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.0.6')]
response = self.br.open("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym&.intl=us")
self.br.select_form(nr=0)
self.br.form['username'] = self.login
self.br.form['passwd'] = self.password
response = self.br.submit()
```

However, when I try this now my login does not succeed, and I am continually redirected back to the login page on any future attempts to access a "private" yahoo url (ie: mail.yahoo.com).

I have noticed that Yahoo login now uses a two step process: 1. Entry username, 2. Enter password. Can anyone tell me if this could be the reason why my form submission in the code above is failing?

If that is the case, is there way to simply click the "Next" button after entering my username, and then click "Sign In" after entering my password?

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: type username -> submit username -> type password -> submit password

Comment: Wow, I really thought I tried that already, but I must have forgotten to do self.br.select_form(nr=0) in between the setting of the username and password values. Thanks! That worked!